# Is this safer to update IE=EmulateIE8 to IE=edge

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have come across a website that needs to be compatible with IE 11. While inspecting its source I have notice following meta tag;

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
```

And checked that its document mode is also 8. In these settings It has a lots of issues. When I updated it to latest i.e. Edge, things become fine again.

Therefore, I have updated the meta tag to;

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

But I just want to know is this safer to update the meta tag I don't know what was there reason of adding `IE=EmulateIE8`. Or I need to add a some condition for specifically IE11?

Comment: Yeah I don't know either. Maybe whoever authored that page is unable to accept the fact that IE11 is standards-compliant and is insistent on making the page look horrible in IE no matter what, so they deliberately set it to emulate an older version.

Comment: I have updated and notice that things getting well no issue yet found. May God bless IE and its developers.